# Wrap text in bootstrap table cells

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am writing a program that extracts data from a product database and displays it in a table. For one of the cells, the text loaded is much longer than expected and thus ended up stretching out the cell horizontally.

I was wondering how I could make it so the text in the cell is wrapped and the table stays within the margins of the page (instead of being stretched past the view size)? The table is styled using bootstrap, I believe that a setting in bootstrap is restricting the text from wrapping.

What it looks like right now: [Current Table]
[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: This is going to be very difficult with tables, you would be better off using Bootstrap's grid `<div class="row text-center"><div class="col-10">Main Column with lots of text</div><div class="col-2">Side Col</div></div>`